# Error : Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Wearable' is using Android.IncludeAndroidResourcesFromAttribute which is no longer supported

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have opened old `xamarin forms` project in VS2019. When I build that I am getting below errors

```
Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Wearable' is using '[assembly: Android.IncludeAndroidResourcesFromAttribute]', which is no longer supported. Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author.  AMR.Android
            
Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Wearable' is using '[assembly: Android.IncludeAndroidResourcesFromAttribute]', which is no longer supported. Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author.  AMR.Android
            
Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Wearable' is using '[assembly: Java.Interop.JavaLibraryReferenceAttribute]', which is no longer supported. Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author.    AMR.Android 
        
Assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Wearable' is using '[assembly: Java.Interop.JavaLibraryReferenceAttribute]', which is no longer supported. Use a newer version of this NuGet package or notify the library author.    AMR.Android
```

I tried many things like update nuget, change target framework but nothing is working out.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is this the nuget that you are using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wearable

Comment: @FreakyAli - yeah looks same only. If I remove all the references everything works fine.

Comment: Try to update your Xamarin.Forms  to latest version too.

Comment: @R15 So did that solve your issue then?